# Where can I find the formulas to compute the Greeks for European Call and Put Options Assuming no annual dividend yield?

Tags: derivatives, greeks, european-options

Every formula I come across involves a $q$ (the annual dividend yield). Where Can I find the formulas to compute the greeks assuming no dividends?

Comment: ...simply set q/y to 0.  Voilà.

Comment: “Every formula”? I am not convinced you looked very hard. On wikipedia’s page for the Black-Scholes Model under the section “The Greeks”, is listed formulas for the Greeks of European calls and puts under no dividends.

Comment: Here you can find a nice table with the Greeks: http://exploringpythonforquantanalysis.blogspot.com/2015/04/the-greeks-options-pricing-in-python.html

Answer (score 1):

As Nap D. Lover said, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#The_Greeks) you have a list without any dividends being considered. It all depends on your model though. If you are using a stochastic volatility model or similar extensions, you get different Greeks. For the Heston model, for instance, see Chapyer 11 in [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118548256). In general however, if you have formulae including a dividend yield $q$, just use the value $q=0$ and you get the case you need. Note that it also always possible to approximate Greeks using a finite differences, e.g. $$ \Delta(t_0,S_0) \approx \frac{V_{t_0}\left(S_0+\frac{1}{2}h\right)-V_{t_0}\left(S_0-\frac{1}{2}h\right)}{h}.$$